# WP7: how to count children of a list box in datatemplate?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have created a pivot control to show all data from my database by using binding data. And the code for the pivot control look like this. And the UI view here: [photo](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-MziOnXrSWaM/UUpvUxlijxI/AAAAAAAAAIU/FH2dV30RlzY/s468/Untitled.png)

I want to solve the problem: **After I tap on an item of listbox (of pivot control), I will get the name of the item.**

**Note:** All controls have no name (x:name). I am trying to use Tag="{Binding CHUPHONG}" replace for x:name.

Could you show me the way to solve that? Or Where I am wrong? Thanks so much!

```
    <controls:PivotItem Header="PHÒNG CHƠI" FontSize="19" Margin="0" Background="{x:Null}">
        <ListBox x:Name="listDSPhong">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Height="120" Width="480" Margin="0,10,0,20">
                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="120" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Source="/LuanVanDeMo;component/xephinhlogo.png"/>

                        <TextBlock Margin="4,44,-98,44" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Chủ phòng:" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock Height="32" Margin="0,5,-98,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Tên phòng:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="98"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,-98,4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Số lượng:" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="98"/>


                        <TextBlock Margin="102,44,-242,44" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TENPHONG}" Width="140" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock Height="32" Margin="102,5,-242,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding CHUPHONG}" Width="140" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="102,0,-134,4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="{Binding SOLUONG}" Width="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" Source="/LuanVanDeMo;component/Images/Buttons/lock.png" Margin="285,35,0,35" Height="50"/>
                    </toolkit:WrapPanel> 

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>              
        </ListBox>
    </controls:PivotItem>            
</controls:Pivot>
```

Answer (score 0):

ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(SelectedIndex);

[Fetching Selected Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.aspx)